# How to fetch a git repo with a program, run from within that repo?

Tags: git, winforms

I have created a utility program that allows me to handle multiple git submodules with much more ease than Gitkraken does. One of the things it does it fetch and pull branches over multiple submodules. This program however is also on the git. If there is an update to the program and you try to pull the branch which this program is on, it is trying to pull a change to itself which will not work since the program exe is locked while the program is being used.

The program is created using Winforms.

Is there either a way to work around this exe lock, by using a temporary exe or something?
What might be a better structure of managing the program?

I'm in general unsure how to structure things in this case. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: The .exe should not be tracked by git to begin with. Usually people use git to track the sources and the files needed for compilation (e.g. project files). Anyway, to work around your problem, you could create a very simple launcher (or adjust your compilation/execution scripts). Instead of just executing the program, copy the executable file and all the files it needs into a temporary folder. Then launch the actual program from there. That way the running instance would run from the temporary folder and lock the files there, not in your source/build directory.

Comment: Could you build to location, which is not under git? Create installer, or something like that. Then you will have executable in one place, and source code - in another.

Comment: @MathijsVanNimwegen : is there a link between the two facts "this exe is located under the git repository" and "I want the git actions to take place within this repository" ?